# sql -insert a new row for each record with a new value?

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to insert a new row for each id with an new value(remove), like below.  How can i do it?

```
id location action
 1  a       add
 2  b       add
 3  c       add
```

TO---->

```
id  location action
 1  a        add
 1  a        remove
 2  b        add
 2  b        remove
 3  c        add
 3  c        remove
```

Comment: Usually by writing and executing a sql query. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TableName (id, Location, action)
SELECT id, Location, 'remove'
FROM TableName
```